# Problems with table placement and with size of an expression

Tags: tables, math-mode

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
 \hline
 Label & Function & Normal & Position Vector \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 1 & $\Gamma(-z_1)$ & $\hat{i}$ & (1,0) \\ 
 2 & $\Gamma(z_1+1)$ & $-\hat{i}$ & (-1,0) \\
 3 & $\Gamma(-z_2)$ & $\hat{j}$ & (0,1) \\
 4 & $\Gamma(z_2-z_1)$ & $\hat{i}-\hat{j}$ & (1,-1) \\
 5 & $\Gamma(z_2+z_1+1)$ & $-\hat{i}-\hat{j}$ & (-1,-1) \\
 6 & $\frac{1}{z_1}$ & $\hat{i}$ & (1,0) \\[1ex] 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I have the following table. I have two problems. The first one is that I want this table to be exactly at the place where I write it in the code. It is always showing at the top of the page. Secondly the last row has `$\frac{1}{z_1}$` which is bit tiny compared to the other functions. Is there any way to increase the size slightly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't want your table to float (move away from where it was used in the code) don't use the `table` environment. A simple `tabular` enclosed in a `center` environment will work.

Comment: the only purpose of the `table` environment is to allow the table to move, but using `[h]`  means you are not allowing it to be at the top or bottom of a page, or on a page with just floats so it doesn't allow it to be placed in many places (latex normally gives a warning and changes it to ht)

Comment: For the fraction size, you can use `\mfrac` from package `nccmath`: it is about 80% of diplaystyle (if you load mathtools, load *nncmath* before).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To support a comment already made by @leandriis, there's no reason for you to employ a `table` environment to begin with, as you (a) don't issue a `\caption` statement to go with the tabular material and (b) believe that the tabular material shouldn't "float" (in the LateX-specific sense of the word). I suggest you employ a simple `center` environment instead.

If the output of `\frac{1}{z_1}` looks too small, how about writing `z_1^{-1}`?

Currently, the fourth column of the table is not in math mode. This seems to be an oversight. Indeed, I suggest you employ an `array` environment, as this will let you cut down considerably on the number of `$` symbols that need to be typed.

In fine math typography, it's customary to omit the 'dots' on top of the letters `i` and `j` when combining them wit a diacritic such as `\hat` or `\tilde`. I suggest you write `\hat{imath` and `\hat{jmath}`.

Finally, I would also like to suggest that you get rid of all vertical lines (hint: they're not needed!) and use only well-spaced horizontal lines, by using the macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` of the `booktabs` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
$\begin{array}{@{} llcc @{}} 
 \toprule
 $Label$ & $Function$ & $Normal$ & $Position Vector$ \\
 \midrule
 1 & \Gamma(-z_1)  &  \hat{\imath} & (1,0) \\ 
 2 & \Gamma(z_1+1) & -\hat{\imath} & (-1,0) \\
 3 & \Gamma(-z_2)  &  \hat{\jmath} & (0,1) \\
 4 & \Gamma(z_2-z_1)& \hat{\imath}-\hat{\jmath} & (1,-1) \\
 5 & \Gamma(z_2+z_1+1)& -\hat{\imath}-\hat{\jmath} & (-1,-1)\\
 6 & z_1^{-1}      &  \hat{\imath} & (1,0) \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{array}$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```